# Finding the intersection of an indexed collection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck with part e of the following question:

$let R_i = \{ x \in \Bbb R | 1 \le x \le 1 + \frac1 i \} = [ 1, 1 + \frac1 i ]$ foreach positive integer $i$.

Now, for part e I thought it was simple enough but when I compared to the prof's answers mine was wrong, but I'm really unsure.

**Part e**: $\bigcap_{i=1}^nR_i=?$

My answer for this question is the following interval: $\bigcap_{i=1}^nR_i=[1, 1 + {1\over n}]$

But the prof had the following: $\bigcap_{i=1}^nR_i=\{1\}$

This doesn't make sense to me as as the smallest interval (in this case $[1, 1 + {1\over n}]$) would be a subset of all the sets from 1 to n (thereby being the intersection of all the sets from 1 to n).

If I'm mistaken, could someone break this down a bit for me? I really don't understand how the answer could be $\{1\}$

Comment: Perhaps your instructor was claiming $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty{R_i} = \{1\}$?

Comment: @Hayden That is actually part `f` of the posted question. I'm thinking this was a mistake on his part but I really want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it was a mistake on his part. The sequence $\langle R_i \rangle_{i=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing (with respect to inclusion) sequence of sets, so if you're taking a finite intersection, it will be the smallest one of those, i.e.., $\bigcap_{i=1}^n{R_i} = R_n$, as you correctly find.